# ListView doesn't show all the items (only the first)

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a list of items that I want to display in a `ListView` using a custom `adapter` but is showing only one item despite the list if daat contains more values..

The code that set the adapter:

```
if (app.familyMemebers != null) {

    Log.d("family", app.familyMemebers.size() + "");
    FamilyMemeberAdapter fad = new FamilyMemeberAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.family_row,
            app.familyMemebers);
    lvFamilyMemebr.setAdapter(fad);

    Log.d("count >>>>", fad.getCount() + "");
}
```

The code of custom adapter is :

```
package com.example.importtoolapp;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FamilyMemeberAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FamilyMemeber> {

    private List<FamilyMemeber> values;
    private Context context;

    public FamilyMemeberAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<FamilyMemeber> values) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Keeps reference to avoid future findViewById()
        valuesViewHolder viewHolder;
        final FamilyMemeber obj = values.get(position);

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.family_row, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new valuesViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvID);
            viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            viewHolder.tvIndrc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvIndrc);
            viewHolder.tvIdnumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvIdnumber);
            viewHolder.tvRelation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvRelation);
            viewHolder.tvBDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvBDate);

            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (valuesViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        if (obj != null) {
            viewHolder.tvID.setText(obj.familyid);
            viewHolder.tvName.setText(obj.fname);
            viewHolder.tvIndrc.setText(obj.indrc);
            viewHolder.tvIdnumber.setText(obj.idnumber);
            viewHolder.tvRelation.setText(obj.hofrelation);
            viewHolder.tvBDate.setText(obj.bdate);
        }
        return v;
    }

    static class valuesViewHolder {
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvID;
        TextView tvIndrc;
        TextView tvIdnumber;
        TextView tvRelation;
        TextView tvBDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: everything looks fine but why are you using textViewResourceId?

Comment: To pass it to the super constructor

Comment: Can you please provide code where you set your adapter. And do you modify your list of values somewhere outside adapter?

Comment: just curiosity are you using listview inside scrollview?

Comment: @santalu yes you are right!

Comment: Don't add your `ListView` to `ScrollView`. Because `ListView` has its own scrolling functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First dont use listview inside scrollview. this is wrong.

if you have to you should calculate listview height manually and set it programatically like below code:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

but remember you can always add header or footer to your listview.